# Why am I getting a Programming error in Django's Python shell?

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I am following the `Django` tutorial for version 1.6 using PostgreSQL on Arch Linux. I'm on part 1 up to this point:

"Give the `Poll` a couple of `Choices`. The create call constructs a new
 `Choice` object, does the `INSERT` statement, adds the choice to the set
 of available choices and returns the new `Choice` object. `Django` creates
 a set to hold the "other side" of a `ForeignKey` relation
 (e.g. a poll's choices) which can be accessed via the API.

```
 >>> p = Poll.objects.get(pk=1)
 # Display any choices from the related object set -- none so far.
 >>> p.choice_set.all()

 []
```

When I run `p.choice_set.all()`, instead of an empty list, I get an error in my shell:

```
ProgrammingError: column "poll_id" of relation "polls_choice" does not exist
```

This is first that I've seen "choice_set" in the tutorial, and I'm not sure what it does. I tried the whole exercise several times and everything worked right until this point -- I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you changed models after doing syncdb?

Comment: Try manually deleting the database by using drop commands and run syncdb again.

Answer (score 0):

Drop Poll and Choice tables and run python manage.py syncdb to recreate them according to your current models.py